Why is `tabularray.sty` not recognized even after downloading it?
I'm getting an error "File 'tabularray.sty' not found" not recognized, even after I did the following:
1). I ran  sudo tlmgr install tabularray
2). Then I ran sudo texhash
3). And then I run the following commands:
rm *.aux
latexmk -pdf MWE.tex

The MWE.tex  file is shown below.  I must be misunderstanding how this works.  The package should be installed after the above commands, correct?
Furthermore, what is the difference between ""File 'tabularray.sty' not found" and the package being installed?
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\begin{document}
\vspace{-15mm}

{\small
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{refs.bib}}
\end{document}

EDIT
The log file is:
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 26 Dec. 2019, version: 4.67.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'pdflatex'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -recorder  "MWE.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./MWE.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06> (./IEEEtran.cls
Document Class: IEEEtran 2015/08/26 V1.8b by Michael Shell
-- See the "IEEEtran_HOWTO" manual for usage information.
-- http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd)
-- Using 8.5in x 11in (letter) paper.
-- Using PDF output.
-- This is a 10 point document.
)
** ATTENTION: Overriding command lockouts (line 2).
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cite/cite.sty)

! LaTeX Error: File `tabularray.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: X

=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Missing input file: 'tabularray.sty' from line
  '! LaTeX Error: File `tabularray.sty' not found.'
Latexmk: Log file says no output from latex
Latexmk: For rule 'pdflatex', no output was made
Failure to make 'MWE.pdf'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
``


possibly the most common reason is that you have two tex systems installed a linux system texlive (managed by apt or similar) and an upstream texlive from tug managed by tlmgr, and you install in one and use the other. If you showed the log file for the example it would help debug

Interesting.  I'll post the log file.

OK so my guess was wrong:-) But I'm a bit confused, you are using texlive 2020 (a bit old) installed from tug not the linux system texlive,  so I would have expected that your tlmgr  command would have given an error that the local 2020 installation was older than the 2024 texlive server and so could not be updated. But tabularray was I think only introduced in 2021 so wouldn't be in texlive 2020 did tlmgr install tabularray give no warning?

You are right!  It is giving me an error (although I don't recall seeing an error when I first installed it): tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2020) is older than remote repository (2024). Cross release updates are only supported with   update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details. 

Yes so you never installed the package which is why you get the error that it's not found

Simplest fix is to install texlive 2024

Normally I would be okay with that, but I'm running out of storage space.  1) Is that the only way around this, or is there a more space-efficient way?  2). If not, then is there a way to get around the original problem "tabularray.sty not found"?

You could get tabularray.sty from ctan but it probably needs a newer expl3 and I would notcattempt to install a current expl3 in such an old installation. Your example runs if you remove the use package line and that is the best answer for texlive 2020
